# Is there any REST endpoints available for forgot password, reset password in wso2?

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there any REST endpoints available for forgot password, reset password in wso2 ?

Answer (score 1):

We are using the User Information Recovery webservices from the Identity Server. This service is SOAP based, but we've put the WSO2 ESB in front of the IS to "RESTify" this service.

http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS450/User+Information+Recovery